# Github etiquette for deciding on whether to create a new project or branch an existing one

Tags: git, github, branch

I am new to Github.  I have ported a small open source Github C project to C++.  I have added a new method, renamed most of the methods to more descriptive names, deleted a bunch of redundant (in my opinion) methods, cleaned up the comments, made it OO, etc.

I have not contacted the original authors about this yet.  So, I'm wondering what the proper etiquette is.  Should I contact them and ask to collaborate on the project?  Should I tell them what I am doing, and if they don't agree, then what?

Or, should I simply create my own version of this project on Github and retain control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For massive refactoring on a project which isn't on GitHub to begin with, one way to move forward is to:

- import the original code (at least the HEAD) to GitHub
- apply your modifications and push them on this GitHub repo
- contact the authors and ask them to [fork your project](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/): they will be able to control their own version of their code, and collaborate with you [through pull request](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/).

Keeping both GitHub repos separate allows for a cleaner separation of concern (massive refactoring for you, legacy support for them) between repos.

Comment: Thank you.  Good answer.  The original C project is on GitHub though.  So, are you suggesting that I should create a new GitHub project, import the original C code, and then "apply my modifications?"  I don't quite understand what you mean by pushing them on my GitHub repo.  Is this done by creating a branch, a fork, or perhaps a different folder?  The links you provided suggest that 2 copies of the code are maintained - one for each repo.  Coordination between the 2 repos are then done manually through "pull requests" - is that right?

Comment: @bob if the original repo was already on Github, then it's you who need to fork that repo, and apply on it your modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ is very different from C (contrary to popular beleifs), I thik your code warrants a new project.

Also I should add that might be a more proper way to deal with the situation would be to create a C++ wrapper that would just link to that C library.  C++ has no problem linking with C (the reverse is not true), and that would keep both camps happy (those who want low-level C library and those who need higher-level OO- and whatever-else-enabled C++ library).

Such a wrapper could even be included into the main project if its compilation could be made optional so that it doesn't get in the way of those who don't need it.

Unfortunately I do not know what's that project is so this is pretty much just hand-waving.